# How to update listview item cell?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem updating android listview items cell.

The listview_item.xml is an ordinary listview item except that it has a hidden panel at the bottom. So the last part of listview_item.xml is LinearLayout that has another button inside it.  This whole layout is set to gone until user clicks on a visible button in the list item.  This sets the hidden LinearLayout to visible and it displays. So far so good.  Now the hidden LinearLayout is open, and showing and I want to close it.  So I click on a button that is inside this previously hidden linear layout and set the visibility to GONE which was its previous state.  The result is nothing happens right away.  The panel remains open until I scroll it out of site and back again.  Then it does not show again.  I'm sorry I don't have the code to post but thats the whole situation.  I just cannot get a list item to refresh on the spot.  Opening using a visible button works fine.  But closing the same panel from a button within the panel seems to do nothing.  I have tried running dataSetChanged() etc from inside the adapter but only scrolling out and into view will close the panel.  Does anyone know why closing is different from opening? Why I get an immediate reaction to setting gone to visible but not the other way. The only difference it seems is that I am firing the event from a button on the previously hidden panel.  Sorry its wordy, but don't have the code in front of me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody here can help you without a code. `notifyDataSetChaged()` is the method that must help you, but if it is not - it obvious that you do something wrong. You must save visibility state of element of each list item in associated with this list item object (or model whatever). Check your code one more time and debug it.

Comment: well there is also view.requestLayout()

Comment: Well, it's absolutely diferent thing. By the way, calling `requestLayout()` for `ListView` or for any of its childrens is a wrong way. Actually, `ListView` already have everything related to `View` redrawing  under the hood, so my opininon doesn't changed: check your code.